# Bxslider not working with Bootstrap Modal box

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bxslider, bootstrap-modal

I am using [bootstrap modal box](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) with [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/). but it is not working.I am changing the content of bxslider with ajax.For sometimes it works when I relaod the page but then it does not work.

Here is my html code.

```
<div id="storeModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <ul class="contact_bxslider">

    </ul>
</div>
```

And jquery code is as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = $('.contact_bxslider').bxSlider({
                  auto:true
                });

    $('.store_pictures_click').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var store_name  =   $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('<?php echo site_url('cart/change_store_pictures'); ?>',{store_name:store_name},
            function(data){
                $('.contact_bxslider').html(data);
                slider.reloadSlider();
                $('#storeModal').modal('show');
            }
        );

    });


});
```

Ajax code...

```
function change_store_pictures(){

        $store_name =   $this->input->post('store_name');
        $this->load->model('Store_Pictures_model'); 
        $data['store_pictures'] =   $this->Store_Pictures_model->get_store_pictures($store_name);

        foreach($data['store_pictures'] as $store_picture){
            ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/full/'.$store_picture->store_picture); ?>" alt="<?php echo $store_picture->store_name; ?>" /></li>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

Please help guys I am not getting its solution.I searched over google and get one result which is saying use width:960px; I did the same but did not work.

Can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Showing the model box first on document on load  and then reloading the slider like this:

```
$('#storeModal').modal('show');

setTimeout(function(){
    slider.reloadSlider();
},200);
```

Comment: Rather than use setTimeout() which can be guesswork if the timing is right, use bootstrap's own modal event triggers. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap's Modal event triggers [described here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events) (Bootstrap's Javascript documentation page at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events).

```
$('#storeModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

This will only fire on the completion of the action that shows the modal, which guarantees it will happen on a successful modal open, as opposed to using a setTimeout() which can be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe Bxslider does a bunch of calculations on positions and sizes when you (re)load it. Maybe the modal dialog being invisible is causing you issues.

Have you tried showing the model box first and then reloading the slider like this:

```
$('#storeModal').modal('show');
slider.reloadSlider();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find bxSlider incredibly unstable when reloading, most likely because it does calculations as Robba has informed us. So building upon Robba's logic and adding my experience:

```
slider.destroySlider();
$('#storeModal').modal('show');
slider.reloadSlider();
```

Every time I have problems with `reloadSlider()`, I always end up destroying it first with `destroySlider()`.